# Oracle , when merge, show " invalid identifier"

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

```
MERGE INTO EP_PR
using(
    select
    SYSDATE AS CREATION_TIME_1,
    1 AS STATUS_1,
    0 AS DELETED_1,
    SYSDATE AS LAST_MOD_TIME_1,
    0 AS EP_STATUS_1,
    SYSDATE AS EP_ISSUE_DATE_1,
    CASE WHEN LENGTH(EKORG)<2 THEN 'UMC1' ELSE EKORG END AS EP_PURORG_1,
    EKGRP AS EP_PURGRP_1
    from ZEPT02
    Where proc_flag='N'

) TABLE1
ON
(
    TABLE1.EP_PR_NO_1=EP_PR.EP_PR_NO
)
WHEN  MATCHED 
THEN UPDATE SET

EP_PR.CREATION_TIME=TABLE1.CREATION_TIME_1,
EP_PR.STATUS=TABLE1.STATUS_1,
EP_PR.DELETED=TABLE1.DELETED_1,
EP_PR.LAST_MOD_TIME=TABLE1.LAST_MOD_TIME_1,
EP_PR.EP_STATUS=TABLE1.EP_STATUS_1,
EP_PR.EP_ISSUE_DATE=TABLE1.EP_ISSUE_DATE_1,
EP_PR.EP_PURORG=TABLE1.EP_PURORG_1,
EP_PR.EP_PURGRP=TABLE1.EP_PURGRP_1;
```

It shows errors that

> SQL error: ORA-00904: "TABLE1"."EP_PR_NO_1": invalid identifier
>   00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
>   *Cause:
>   *Action:

I'm trying to google it, 
but my on clause "TABLE1"."EP_PR_NO_1" didn't appear at the merge column,
where did it wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Your USING doesn't define a column named EP_PR_NO_1 :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't defined `TABLE1.EP_PER_NO_1` anywhere, which is exactly what the Oracle error is telling you.

Comment: My probles was  ON ("id" = 3)   with "" . Need  ON (id = 3)